# Uninstall DBeaver

Tags: uninstall

I installed an application named DBeaver for mysql management.
I have tried:

```
sudo apt-get remove
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

But neither can find the package...

I tried to remove it from Featured applications, But it is not there!

How can I remove this application?

Comment: How was it installed?

Comment: It was downloaded and installed from  https://dbeaver.io/
I had to install the file from my computer.
I think with apt-get from the command line, but it was downloaded...

Comment: It was dbeaver-ce  6.0.5_amd64. deb  I may just had clicked it and opened up the install.

Comment: Never mind I got it, you have to do it with dbeaver-ce to remove it...
You call it with dbeaver  but you have to use the -ce to remove it.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to remove it with `sudo dpkg -P dbeaver-ce` or 
 `sudo dpkg -r dbeaver-ce` to preserve configuration files.

Alternatively, search for the exact package name with `dpkg -l | grep dbeaver`, and substitute it to the first command.